# What is a more elegant way of dealing with multiple or's in an if statment

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I have this code to check every char in a char array if it satisfies a set number of properties:
 * Is a number
 * or is a (+, -, *, /)

```
bool chkArray(char input[]) {
    for (auto x = 0; x < strlen(input); x++) {
        if (isdigit(input[x]) || input[x] == '+' || input[x] == '-' || input[x] == '*' || input[x] == '/' || input[x] == ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I feel like there is a more elegant way of dealing with the multiple or's that check for the (+, -, *, /). Something like this:

```
bool chkArray(char input[]) {
    for (auto x = 0; x < strlen(input); x++) {
        if (isdigit(input[x]) || input[x] == '+', '-', '*', '/', ' ') {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So I am now wondering if anybody has an alternative to the original code to make it more elegant ?

Comment: Write a function to encapsulate that comparison.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm annoying to you but I am quite new to c++ and programming in general but could you give an example cause I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @JensLindström you don't understand what a function is?

Comment: @bolov no I just did not understand what meant by encapsulation the comparison

Comment: Looks like you are writing a parser, probably better use a special tool or lib for that. Like `std::regex` or `bison` or `boost::spirit` etc

Comment: `bool is_valid_char(char ch) { return isdigit(ch) || ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == ' '; }` And with that, the `if` statement becomes much simpler: `if (!is_valid_char(input[x]) return false;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oldschool solution is to use [`std::strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strchr):

```
if (isdigit(input[x]) || std::strchr("+-*/ ", input[x]))
```

Comment: Emphasis at ***oldschool*** 'ole chum ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since c++14 the most idiomatic way to do that is probably to use a [`std::string` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) and the [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

int main()
{
    std::string input = "Hello world5!"s;

    for(auto c : input) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha 
                  << (std::isdigit(c) || "+-*/ "s.find(c) != std::string::npos) 
                  << '\n';
    }      
}
```

Output:

> ```
> false
> false
> false
> false
> false
> true
> false
> false
> false
> false
> false
> true
> false
> ```

See a working [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b68742dbe02b10e2).

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest creating a function that checks if it is one of the values you want and have it return a boolean value 
Something like

```
bool Contains(char in)
{
     return in=='+' || in =='-' || in == '*' || in == '/' || in== ' ';
}
```

Although there are better ways to do this such as passing an array of charecters to check against instead of doing it hard coded.