# Check whether a char is anything other than 4 variables with ! operand

Tags: c++

Im trying to check whether a char variable is anything other than 4 characters and if so end the program. However my last two attempts have failed being:

```
if(budget < 0 || selection != 'G' || selection != 'B' || selection != 'P' || selection != 'O'))
```

and

```
if(budget < 0 || selection != ('G' || 'B' || 'P' || 'O'))
```

I understand why the first is wrong and the second is my attempt to fix it. How can I check that char selection is not any of these 4 variables without a logical error?

Comment: `selection != 'B' || selection != 'P'` is always true. If B is entered, then it's not P. If P is entered, then it's not B. If neither is entered, then ...

Comment: `selection != ('G' || 'B' || 'P' || 'O'))` is `selection != 1`.

Comment: Are you aware of `&&`?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||` when comparing the characters: `if (budget < 0 || (selection != 'G' && selection != 'B' && selection != 'P' && selection != 'O'))`

Comment: Vote to reopen. The problem is reproducible and it was not caused by typos. It was caused by misunderstanding C++ syntax. Close voters: if you or I wrote that it would be a typo, but for a beginner it’s not. Try and remember what it was like when you were just getting started.

Comment: `!` is an *operator,* not an 'operand'. @PeteBecker It's a typo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a variable is not equal to multiple things in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631573/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-not-equal-to-multiple-things-in-c)

Comment: @user207421 -- of course! How silly of me! I should have realized that the person who posted the code intended to type `&&` and not `||`, and just didn't notice that they had typed the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

`selection != 'G' || selection != 'B'` is always true, because if `selection == 'G'`, then right side is true, and if `selection == 'B'`, then the left side is true and in all other cases both sides are true. Only case in which logical OR is false is when both sides are false.

> `selection != ('G' || 'B' || 'P' || 'O')`

Now you're comparing a character to `'G' || 'B' || 'P' || 'O'` which is a `true` boolean expression.

To rephrase "is not any of a b c d" in basic logical propositions, you say: "Is not a AND is not b AND is not c AND is not d". The operator that you're looking for is AND (i.e. `&&`) not OR (i.e. `||`).

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, your `if` statements will always be true. This is because you are using `||` which is the `or` operator.

When you `or` two pieces of data, it will return `true` as long as *at least one* of those pieces of data is not zero. So when you say

```
(selection != 'G' || selection != 'B')
```

this will always return true because `selection` cannot be both G and B at the same time.

For example, let's say `selection = 'G'`

Then the problem becomes

```
(['G'] != 'G' || ['G'] != 'B')
```

Simplifying

```
(false || true)
(true)
```

So no matter what `selection` is, this statement will always return `true`.

When you add more `or` statements it only exacerbates the problem.

---

As for your second attempt,

```
('G' || 'B' || 'P' || 'O')
```

These chars are all non-zero values, so this entire statement can be rewritten as:

```
(true or true or true or true)
```

Which obviously returns a true, but more importantly, doesn't compare anything to `selection`.

Operators such as `||`,`==`, and `!=` only care about what is on either side of them, and they don't act like multiplication, there's no distributive property, so putting a `!=` in front of `('G' || 'B' || 'P' || 'O')` doesn't compare anything meaningful, it just results in `selction != true`, as it will do all of the comparisons inside of the parenthesis before the comparison to `selection`.

---

There are a few solutions you could use. The most simple would be to use an `and` operator (`&&`) instead of an `or` operator. The `and` operator only returns true if both of its operands are true, and so chaining them in a fashion similar to

```
if(selection != 'G' && selection != 'B' && selection != 'P' && selection != 'O')
```

will give you the behavior you want. The only way this expression returns true is if `selection` doesn't equal any one of those four characters. I'll demonstrate that below.

```
selection = 'A'
if( ['A'] != 'G' && ['A'] != 'B' && ['A'] != 'P' && ['A'] != 'O' )
if( true && true && true && true )
if( true )

selection = 'P'
if( ['P'] != 'G' && ['P'] != 'B' && ['P'] != 'P' && ['P'] != 'O' )
if( true && true && false && true )
if( true && true && false ) //false && true returns false
if( true && false )
if( false )
```

So as you can see, it only returns true if it doesn't equal any of the specified characters.

---

Finally, if you do want to use `or` operators, you can change your code a little bit and make it work.

```
if( !(selection == 'G' || selection == 'B' || selection == 'P' || selection == 'O') )
```

In this, if `selection` equals any of the four characters then the inner statement will return `true`, which will then be inverted by the `!`, resulting in a false. If `selection` doesn't equal any of the characters, then the inner statement will return a `false`, inverting into a `true`.